# jQuery @ Keypress detection in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, keypress

I have a simple jquery a keypress code that detects when the user types the @ key.
The problem:  Works great in webkit (Chrome/Safari) but does absolutely nothing in FF.

The JS fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cUzzt/

The code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).keypress(function(e) {
          if(e.keyCode == 64) { //@ Symbol
              alert("You pressed the @ key");
          }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You want charCode:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).keypress(function(e) {
          if(e.charCode == 64) { //@ Symbol
              alert("You pressed the @ key");
          }
    });
});
```